# Java - Use loaded Image multiple times

Tags: java, lag

I'm trying to load and a bunch of Images into a program and repaint them 60times per second.My Problem is that I get a CPU usage of over 20% and the program isn't even finished.

This is the loop that load's the Image:

```
    for(int i = 0;i < LevelCompiler.Objectlenght;i++) {
        LevelCompiler.objects[i].drawObjects(g);
    }
```

and this is the drawObjects methode:

```
g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
    g.drawImage(TextureSystem.textureSystem(TextureID), x, y, width, height, null);
```

The textureSystem methode that load's the imgae:

```
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class TextureSystem {
static String TexturePath;
static BufferedImage img;

public static BufferedImage textureSystem(int tid) {
    TexturePath = "/textures/Objects/SObject+" + tid + ".jpg";
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(ResourceLoader.load((TexturePath)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return img;

}
}
```

and this is the ResourceLoader from above

```
import java.io.InputStream;

public final class ResourceLoader {

 public static InputStream load(String path) {
    InputStream input = ResourceLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
    if (input == null) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
    return input;
}

}
```

I assume that the high CPU usage is because I'm loading the image again and again.Any suggetions how for another methode?

Comment: Load the image once, hold them in memory? Before you actually start optimizing, I would advice you to benchmark your application to see where most of the computational time is spent. [JVisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) is one tool you can use.

Comment: I feel stupid, you saved my day, I m sorry for this obvious question. I solved it by saving the image to a BufferedImage variable when creating the object, and then reuse it.